# How do I copy text to system clipboard in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.6, glade, pyperclip

I'm trying to understand how I can get a program to copy a given text to the system clipboard and then be able to paste that text to any other application systemwide.

I have designed a GUI with Glade and have a GtkEntry and a Button to copy the text, everything works well GUI-wise except I can't get the text in GtkEntry to be copied to the system clipboard when I click the copy button and therefore I am not able to paste it anywhere else.

Here is a bit of the code that I wrote in Python 3.6

```
def on_copy_Button_clicked(self, button, data=None):
    text_Field = builder.get_object("text_Field")
    text_Field = str(text_Field.get_text())
    pyperclip.copy(text_Field)
```

> **Copy comment**:
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File "/home/vittorio/Self-made_programs/Python/Simple Copy-Paste/simple copy-paste.py", line 17, 
>     in on_copy_Button_clicked pyperclip.copy(text_Field) 
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 616, 
>     in lazy_load_stub_copy return copy(text) 
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 150,
>     in copy_gtk cb = gtk.Clipboard() 
> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 69, 
>     in getattr raise AttributeError(_static_binding_error)
> ```

Comment: What gets printed if you do `pyperclip.paste()` ?

Comment: Have you verified that `text_Field` holds what you expected?

Comment: Ok so I managed to sort this out by following this guide 'https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/clipboard.html' only thing now is I'm trying to apply the same thing instead of using a GtkEntry, using a GtkTextView..